# Formidable doesn't work outside localhost

Tags: node.js, typescript, file-upload, formidable

I've made a basic file uploader website using formidable. The file uploader works on my localhost, however when other devices use my website to upload files it doesn't work and I get an error from `await fs.writeFile(newPath, rawData);`. I checked formidable's `files` object and the `files.name` property was set to `''` (it's set to the name of the file when I upload, but when other devices upload it's set to `''`). Additionally when other devices upload, the file at the path `files.path` is always empty.

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs/promises";
import { Fields, Files, IncomingForm } from "formidable";
const formidable = require("formidable");
const PORT = 8000;
const app = express();
const resourcePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "..", "resources");

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "public", "index.html"));
});

app.post("/api/upload", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("/api/ hit");

    const form: IncomingForm = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    // let form: IncomingForm = formidable({ multiples: true });
    form.parse(req, async (err: any, fields: Fields, files: Files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("THERE WAS ERROR!");
            next(err);
            return;
        }

        const oldPath: string = files.someExpressFiles.path;
        const newPath: string = path.join(
            __dirname,
            files.someExpressFiles.name
        );

        // raw data
        let rawData: any;
        try {
            rawData = await fs.readFile(oldPath);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("1", err);
        }

        try {
            await fs.writeFile(newPath, rawData);
            res.send("Successfully uploaded");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("2", err);
        }
    });
});
```

This is formidable's `files` object when a computer other than my laptop uploads:

```
files {
  someExpressFiles: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 0,
    path: 'C:\\Users\\myName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_75928c3230dd986d613067faeb3df9ff',
    name: '',
    type: 'application/octet-stream',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: null,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: 'C:\\Users\\myName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\upload_75928c3230dd986d613067faeb3df9ff',
      fd: 3,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      autoClose: true,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 0,
      closed: false,
      [Symbol(kFs)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kIsPerformingIO)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```

My html file:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form action="/api/upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <!-- <input type="file" multiple /> -->
            <input type="file" name="someExpressFiles" multiple="multiple" />
            <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this happens and a solution to it such that file uploading will work from another device?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually no errors. The error I got was caused by user error due to bad design in the original code base which looked slightly different from the code posted here. The code posted here actually works completely fine.